# Why i can't set background image on winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

Not sure why after i restart my Visual studios, I was unable to set a background image for my form. Anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

This is the error:

> [[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\PDI APP Edit as per feedback\PDIPROTOTYPE2\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs'.]

[image: Encountered error when i try to set a background image for my form]

Comment: It couldn't find the file at that path

Comment: `after i restart my Visual studios`  how many do you have?

Comment: Please include error messages as text, _not only as images_.

Comment: Spaces in the path is the issue.

Comment: @John added the error in text thanks.

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow 1

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks for the suggestion, I've tried to change my file name without spaces, but i  still cant attach a background image.

Comment: Can you share the filename which you are setting in the resource file? And how are you setting?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya C:\Users\user\Desktop\PDI_APP_EDIT_FOR_TO\PDIPROTOTYPE2\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya sorry im quite a newbie to c#, what do you mean by how am  i setting it?

Comment: How are you setting BackGround Image of the form?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya properties menu of the form->selecting Backgroundimage -> backgroundimage properties windows open->Import image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that image file from your Resources, rename the file without space, save and rebuild your project and check whether the same error occurs or not? I believe spaces in the file name can cause this error.

To remove
Go to Properties >> Resources >> double click to open and select your image file and press delete.

If you are not getting your file there then try to open **Resources.Designer.cs** and press Ctrl+F and search for a file name and remove that function which is used to get your file and then try to add your file again.

Remember to always use code standard naming for each of your file, classes, properties, and methods. This will be beneficial for you as well as for your team to collaborate with you in your code.